# Discord бот. Не получается писать в чат

Tags: python, бот, discord-api

Возникла проблема, не понимаю, как отправить сообщение в чат

Вот пример кода документации на гитхабе

```
client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds
```

мой код

```
client = Bot(description="MilkiweedBot", command_prefix="-", pm_help = False)
async def notif():
    channel = discord.Object(id='415802387840892928')
    await client.send_message(channel, 'testest')

client.loop.create_task(notif())
client.run('***token***')
```

При запуске бот активный, но никак не хочет отправлять сообщения

еще пробовал задать id вместо строки - цифрами, все равно никакого результата.

еще пытался таким образом делать

```
@client.event
async def notif(context):
     await client.send_message(client.get_channel('415802387840892928'), "testest')
```

тоже никак

В документации куча примеров для обработки входящего элемента, например когда пользователь сделал какое-то действие, тогда все окей.

А просто отправить сообщение в чат - не могу разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!bot'):
        msg = 'сообщение'
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю правильно будет

```
client = discord.Client
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!notif'):
        await client.send_message(discord.Object('415802387840892928'), 'testest')
```